# Init array of structs in Go

Tags: arrays, struct, go

I'm newbie in Go. This issue is driving me nuts. How do you init array of structs in Go?

```
type opt struct {
    shortnm      char
    longnm, help string
    needArg      bool
}

const basename_opts []opt { 
        opt {
            shortnm: 'a', 
            longnm: "multiple", 
            needArg: false, 
            help: "Usage for a"}
        },
        opt {
            shortnm: 'b', 
            longnm: "b-option", 
            needArg: false, 
            help: "Usage for b"}
    }
```

The compiler said it expecting `;` after `[]opt`.

Where should I put the braces `{` to init my array of struct?

Answer (score 179):

It looks like you are trying to use (almost) straight up C code here. Go has a few differences.

- First off, you can't initialize arrays and slices as `const`. The term `const` has a different meaning in Go, as it does in C. The list should be defined as `var` instead.
- Secondly, as a style rule, Go prefers `basenameOpts` as opposed to `basename_opts`.
- There is no `char` type in Go. You probably want `byte` (or `rune` if you intend to allow unicode codepoints).
- The declaration of the list must have the assignment operator in this case. E.g.: `var x = foo`.
- Go's parser requires that each element in a list declaration ends with a comma.
  This includes the last element. The reason for this is because Go automatically inserts
  semi-colons where needed. And this requires somewhat stricter syntax in order to work.

For example:

```golang
type opt struct {
    shortnm      byte
    longnm, help string
    needArg      bool
}

var basenameOpts = []opt { 
    opt {
        shortnm: 'a', 
        longnm: "multiple", 
        needArg: false, 
        help: "Usage for a",
    },
    opt {
        shortnm: 'b', 
        longnm: "b-option", 
        needArg: false, 
        help: "Usage for b",
    },
}
```

An alternative is to declare the list with its type and then use an `init` function to fill it up. This is mostly useful if you intend to use values returned by functions in the data structure. `init` functions are run when the program is being initialized and are guaranteed to finish before `main` is executed. You can have multiple `init` functions in a package, or even in the same source file.

```golang
    type opt struct {
        shortnm      byte
        longnm, help string
        needArg      bool
    }

    var basenameOpts []opt

    func init() { 
        basenameOpts = []opt{
            opt {
                shortnm: 'a', 
                longnm: "multiple", 
                needArg: false, 
                help: "Usage for a",
            },
            opt {
                shortnm: 'b', 
                longnm: "b-option", 
                needArg: false, 
               help: "Usage for b",
            },
        }
    }
```

Since you are new to Go, I strongly recommend reading through [the language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). It is pretty short and very clearly written. It will clear a lot of these little idiosyncrasies up for you.

Comment: opt is redundant in an array

Answer (score 63):

Adding this just as an addition to @jimt's excellent answer:

one common way to define it all at initialization time is using an anonymous struct:

```
var opts = []struct {
    shortnm      byte
    longnm, help string
    needArg      bool
}{
    {'a', "multiple", "Usage for a", false},
    {
        shortnm: 'b',
        longnm:  "b-option",
        needArg: false,
        help:    "Usage for b",
    },
}
```

This is commonly used for testing as well to define few test cases and loop through them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I came across this syntax was getting a bit frustrated that the concept hadn't been introduced in the resource I was reading and that I was having trouble finding the name online.

Answer (score 5):

You can have it this way:

It is important to mind the commas after each struct item or set of items.

```
earnings := []LineItemsType{    
        LineItemsType{    
            TypeName: "Earnings",    
            Totals: 0.0,    
            HasTotal: true,    
            items: []LineItems{    
                LineItems{    
                    name: "Basic Pay",    
                    amount: 100.0,
                },    
                LineItems{    
                    name: "Commuter Allowance",    
                    amount: 100.0,
                },
            },
        },
        LineItemsType{    
            TypeName: "Earnings",    
            Totals: 0.0,    
            HasTotal: true,    
            items: []LineItems{    
                LineItems{    
                    name: "Basic Pay",    
                    amount: 100.0,
                },    
                LineItems{    
                    name: "Commuter Allowance",    
                    amount: 100.0,
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this answer while searching for how to initialize a slice of structs. I've been working with Go just a few months myself so I'm not sure if  this was true at the time of the question or its just a new update but its not(no longer) necessary to restate the type. See a refactored version of @jimt's example

```
type opt struct {
    shortnm      byte
    longnm, help string
    needArg      bool
}

var basenameOpts = []opt { 
    {
        shortnm: 'a', 
        longnm: "multiple", 
        needArg: false, 
        help: "Usage for a",
    },
    {
        shortnm: 'b', 
        longnm: "b-option", 
        needArg: false, 
        help: "Usage for b",
    },
}
```